# lagging parameters in panda?

Tags: python, pandas, parameters

I'm new to panda. I have a dataframe of TTI which is sorted by hour of a day for many years. I want to add a new column showing last year's tti value for each value. I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
tti = pd.read_csv("c:\\users\\Mehrdad\\desktop\\Hourly_TTI.csv")
tti['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(tti['Date'])
tti['last_year'] = tti['TTI'].shift(1,freq='1-Jan-2009')
print tti.head(10)
```

but I don't know how to define frequency value for shift! So that it would shift my data for one year behind my first date which is 01-01-2010.!?

Comment: Don't you want `freq='Y'` for year?

Comment: Hi, John. I did use 'Y' for frequency but I got this 'valueError' message.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['last_year'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=1))
df['new_value'] = df.loc[df['last_year'],:]
```

`df.shift` can only move by a fixed distance.
Use offset to create a new datetime index and retrieve the value using the new index. Be aware to truncate the date of the first year.